# Python Type issue when Converting a CSV to custom JSON format

Tags: python, json

I am trying to convert a CSV to a specific format. I have succeeded getting the the format desired but i now realize it has treated all csv values as string, where some should be floats, or literal, or int.

Is there a method to correctly format the columns values to the desired for the JSON dump. I am sure there is also a simpler way to accomplish this too.

```
j = []

with open("output.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:

    row["id"] = row["Id2"]
    row["ideca"] = row["schemaV"]
    row["schem"] = row["schema"]
    row["lore"] = row["serialNumber"]
    row["tore"] = row["msgschem"]
    row["fore"] = row["dschema"]
    row["created"] = row["created"]
    row["loaded"] = row["created"]

    row["geometry1"] = {
        "type": "point",
        "coordinates": row["latlong"]
    }

    row["location1"] = {
        "timestamp": row["timestamp"],
        "geometry": row["geometry1"]
    }

    row["ignition1"] = {
        "timestamp": row["timestamp"],
        "state": row["Value"]
    }

    row["data"] = {
      "engine_status": row["Value"],
      "state": row["Value"],
      "switch_status": row["Value"],
      "latitude": row["lat"],
      "longtitude": row["long"],
      "plantNumber": row["plantno"],
      "ignition": row["ignition1"],
      "location": row["location1"]

    }


    del(row[""])
    del(row["Epoch"])
    del(row["AssetId"])
    del(row["Value"])
    del(row["lat"])
    del(row["long"])
    del(row["serialNumber"])
    del(row["plantno"])
    del(row["msgschem"])
    del(row["dschema"])
    del(row["created"])
    del(row["intEpoch"])
    del(row["timestamp"])
    del(row["latlong"])
    del(row["Id"])
    del(row["Id2"])
    del(row["ignition1"])
    del(row["geometry1"])
    del(row["location1"])

    # Collect the changed row in the list of rows.
    j.append(row)

print(json.dumps(j, indent=4))
```

Data example as below:

```
    Id  Epoch   AssetId Value   lat long    serialNumber    plantno Id2 schemaV schema  msgschem    dschema created intEpoch    timestamp   latlong
0   1538317366  875 0   -1.6478 1.9428  1688889 1042225 168888;1538317366   1    d2xxxage    mxxx;v1    Sxxxxs  154900000   15900000    30/09/2018  2:22:46 PM  [ -1.647766499999996, 1.9428143 ]
```

Comment: From CSV, all will be imported as String  as you've mentioned.
Just type cast columns by doing `"state": float(row["Value"])`

Comment: @Ari Simple as that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ari Was correct. Simply putting:

```
"state": float(row["Value"])
```

Solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

your code is complicated by putting things into the `row` dictionary and then having to cleaning up again afterwards.  I'd do something more similar to:

```
import csv
import json

results = []
for row in csv.DictReader(fileobj):
    # parse non-string columns
    value = float(row["Value"])
    latlong = json.loads(row['latlong'])

    # create nested structures
    ignition = {
        "timestamp": row["timestamp"],
        "state": value,
    }
    location = {
        "timestamp": row["timestamp"],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "point",
            "coordinates": latlong,
        }
    }

    # create dict and append to results
    results.append({
        'id': row['Id2'],
        'ideca': row["schemaV"],
        'schem': row["schema"],
        'lore': row["serialNumber"],
        'tore': row["msgschem"],
        'fore': row["dschema"],
        'loaded': row["created"],
        'engine_status': value,
        'state': value,
        'switch_status': value,
        'latitude': row["lat"],
        'longtitude': row["long"],
        'plantNumber': row["plantno"],
        'ignition': ignition,
        'location': location,
    })
```

note that I'm also parsing out the JSON looking `latlong` column in the hope that's useful.  it was kind of awkward to see what was relevant in your code so things might have moved around a bit, but hopefully it's easier to see what's going on like this